# Sending Associative Array From PHP through ajax back to PHP

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I am receiving an associative array from PHP via $_GET through the following url:
`example.com/example.php?itemcount[A]=2&itemcount[B]=3`

The result of using json_encode() is the following:
`{ "A" : "2", "B" : "3" }`

I want to send this to another php file via ajax. How can I do this?

EDIT:
I additionally want to send other variables such as through `data: {"var1" : "val1", "var2" : "val2", "var3" : "val3" }`.

How can I send all of these?

Comment: do you want to send it to a php from another server?

Comment: you can do this by defining an ajax call which will send the result of your first call to a second URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: '/path/hello.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
               //your code here..
            },
            data: jsonDataVar   //jsonDataVar = { "A" : "2", "B" : "3" }
        });
```

Comment: What if I already have variables and values in the form `data: { var1: val1, var2: val2 }` and want the array in addition to that?

Comment: what data you want to send ? if its json, store it in variable and send it as per my answer.

Comment: so i have `{ var1: val1, var2: val2 } and { "A" : "2", "B" : "3 }`. How do I send all of that?

Comment: you could do like var finalObj = json1.concat(json2); and send finalObj in your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to send the result from json_encode() to another server in PHP via POST.

see [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

I avoided the issue by keeping the php code in the same file as I am receiving the array.